# Add CSS in Angular based on dynamically populated HTML

Tags: html, css, angular

Brand new to Angular with little front-end experience. I'm not even sure where to start. I have a mat-table with a hard-coded datasource (linking to DB in the future) where I need to change the background color of cells in a column based on whether display "pass" or "fail." Where do I even begin with this? I understand the logic is:

```
if (result == "pass") { add green styling}
else {add red styling}
```

However, how does this translate into reality with Angular?
Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65974929/ngstyle-selects-items-randomly/65982093#65982093

Answer (score 1):

**use this one like :**

```
  <div [ngStyle]="{'background-color': result === 'pass' ? 'green' : 'red' }"></<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

NgStyle would be the best approach to use. Check out the example below:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-color': result === 'pass' ? 'green' : 'red' }"></<div>
```

If the result equals 'pass', the background color of your div will be green, alternatively, it will be red.

For more information, [click here](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/built-in-directives/ngstyle-and-ngclass/).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not providing a reproducible example, I'm going to take an example from the official `Angular Material` table [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview).

Given this table, you could add whatever style you want to each of your cells given a condition like this:

**component**

```js
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  { position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H' },
  { position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He' },
  { position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li' },
  { position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be' },
  { position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B' },
  { position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C' },
  { position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N' },
  { position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O' },
  { position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F' },
  { position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne' },
];

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
}
```

**template HTML**

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>No.</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.position }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.name }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Weight</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.weight }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- HERE -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Symbol</th>
    <td 
      [ngStyle]="{ 
        'background-color: element.symbol === 'pass' ? red : green' 
      }" 
      mat-cell 
      *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.symbol }}
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: check this SO   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65974929/ngstyle-selects-items-randomly/65982093#65982093